# Problemas para login en java por encriptacion

Tags: java, vb.net

Estoy haciendo un método de Login en Java pero me encontré con un problema, ya que en la base de datos las contraseñas están encriptadas debido a que la base de datos se comparte con otro sistema que fue hecho en *Visual Basic*.
Este es el código de *VB* donde encriptan las contraseñas:

```vb
Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal cleanString As String) As String

    Dim clearBytes As Byte()
    Dim hashedBytes As Byte()

    clearBytes = New UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(cleanString)
    hashedBytes = CType(CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("MD5"), HashAlgorithm).ComputeHash(clearBytes)

    Return BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes)

End Function
```

Un ejemplo de una contraseña en la base es esta: `97-58-d5-42-85-77-01` en la cual la contraseña real es `301985`.

¿Podrían ayudarme a cómo poder hacer la comparación en el método de logueo en Java?

Este es el metodo que normalmente utilizo para autentificar:

public int Autentificar(String user, String pass){

```
    int respuesta=0;

    try {
        con.Conectar();
        String sql="SELECT dbo.seg_usr_usuarios.usr_username, dbo.seg_usr_usuarios.usr_password FROM dbo.seg_usr_usuarios INNER JOIN dbo.pos_pos_postulantes ON dbo.seg_usr_usuarios.usr_codigo = dbo.pos_pos_postulantes.pos_usuario where dbo.seg_usr_usuarios.usr_username ='?'  and dbo.seg_usr_usuarios.usr_password='?'";

        ps = con.getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, this.usr_username);
        ps.setString(2, this.usr_password);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.absolute(1)){
            respuesta=rs.getInt(1);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al Autentificar"+e);
    }finally{
        con.Desconectar();
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

Al cual en este caso que esta encriptada no tengo conocimiento de como modificar esa parte de la contraseña

Probando un método de encriptacion que encontré que era este:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String textoSinEncriptar = "301985";
    String textoEncriptadoConMD5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(textoSinEncriptar);
    String textoEncriptadoConSHA = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(textoSinEncriptar); 
    System.out.println("Texto Encriptado con MD5 : " + textoEncriptadoConMD5); 
    System.out.println("Texto Encriptado con SHA : " + textoEncriptadoConSHA);
}
```

Comment: Hola Oscar. Sin duda alguien te puede ayudar, pero lo apropiado sería que tu hagas el esfuerzo primero y luego nos preguntas si te trancas en algo específico.

Comment: Claro que si y por lo mismo es que pedi ayuda debido a que login ya he hecho yo varios, porque eso no es ningun problema ni tampoco dificil pero mi consulta fue porque nunca me habia encontrado con ese  tipo de problema de que hubiese una contraseña encriptada y e buscado informacion acerca de ello e incluso hice pruebas con la misma contraseña pero no encriptan de la misma manera, he ahi el detalle de porque preferi preguntar...............

Comment: Entonces perfecto. Comparte el código que intentastes para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: De paso, usando el código VB.NET, le versión encriptada de `301985` es `97-58-D2-42-85-77-01-3B-D0-11-11-FC-61-C5-EB-C0`. Es mas largo y diferente de lo que pusistes en la pregunta. Ver [aquí](http://rextester.com/VXCH72689). ¿Puedes aclarar esa diferencia por favor?

Comment: es la misma solo que reconoce los primeros 20 caracteres en la base de datos debido a que el campo de la contraseña es de varchar (20) ,

Comment: bueno, y hay una diferencia con el `d5` y el `D2`, y que uno usa minúscula y el otro mayúscula. Pero bueno, detalles. Me avisas cuando editas tu pregunta con el código en Java que intentastes, así te podemos ayudar. No es tan complicado.

Comment: si ese fue error mio al formular la pregunta, pero revise el link que me compartiste y si coinciden con los de la base, ya actualice la pregunta con el codigo java que utilizo, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Veo el código, pero no veo donde en ese código has intentado encriptar la cadena. En uno de tus comentarios anteriores dijistes: *incluso hice pruebas con la misma contraseña pero no encriptan de la misma manera*. Eso es lo que quisiera ver.

Comment: Ummm las pruebas que hice fueron aparte, probando un metodo de encriptacion que encontre que era este:

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String textoSinEncriptar = "301985";

        String textoEncriptadoConMD5 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(textoSinEncriptar)
;
        String textoEncriptadoConSHA = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(textoSinEncriptar);

        System.out.println("Texto Encriptado con MD5 : " + textoEncriptadoConMD5);

        System.out.println("Texto Encriptado con SHA : " + textoEncriptadoConSHA);

       
    }

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar las equivalencias adecuadas para las 3 etapas principales siguientes:

1. Convertir la cadena a bytes usando el encoding correcto.

   En este caso, cuando VB.NET usa la clase `UnicodeEncoding`, este usa *UTF-16* en *little-endian byte order*. En Java,  esto equivale a usar `getBytes("UTF-16LE")`.
2. Aplicar la transformación MD5.

   En Java, esto se hace usando `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(bytes)`
3. Formatear el resultado en una cadena HEX.

   En Java, la forma más sencilla, que yo sepa, es usar `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes)`. El único problema es que este no incluye los `-` entre cada "byte". De modo que hay que usar un método alternativo.

El código resultante es:

```
private static String Encrypt(String cleanString) throws Exception {
    byte[] clearBytes = cleanString.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    byte[] hashedBytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(clearBytes);
    
    // Convertir a cadena HEX.
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(hashedBytes.length * 3);
    for(byte b : hashedBytes) {
        if (buf.length() != 0) {
            buf.append("-");
        }
        
        buf.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/GCUF89779)

Y a modo de comparación: [Demo VB.NET](http://rextester.com/VXCH72689).

Comment: Muchas Gracias Por la ayuda,

Comment: ya con esto solo me queda acortar el resultado para que concuerden con los 20 caracteres de la base de datos...... gracias por la clase.